# How to prevent images from resizing when the users increases the browser text size

Tags: css

Is there a way to prevent the resizing of images in the `<img>` tag when a user is adjusting the site font size?

I have a container with a fixed height and when the text is enlarged on the site, it is pushing images outside of that container.

Edit: 
Here is an abridged version of the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/0wk5bg17/

Comment: so you are saying that when user adjusts font size.... your image is pushed out of a fixed height div. So the image is not in fact being resized? just being pushed by larger lettering... maybe make the container not fixed w/h?

Comment: The image is being resized. I updated the original post with a code example.

Comment: I guess he means page complete rescale by mouse wheel.. I guess in this case you can use the onresize Event of the window to rescale all images to the old size. Its a ugly method. On the other hand even this site will becomes unreadble if you push her to far :)